# at least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

Hello i try to create simple AI program , so i define two grammar and load them and i get this error at least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition.
the error from visual studio is :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: At least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition.

here is the code
this is the class

```
class DefineGrammar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Define Choices
    /// </summary>
    Choices greeting;
    Choices DateAndTime;


    /// <summary>
    /// Define the Grammar var
    /// </summary>
    Grammar greetingGrammar;
    Grammar DateAndTimeGrammar;

    SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    public void LoadGrammar()
    {
        // put the data inside the choice
        greeting = new Choices(new string[] { "hello", "how are you" });
        DateAndTime = new Choices(new string[] { "what time is it", "what is today" });

        // Define Grammar builder to put the choice inside it
        GrammarBuilder greetingGrammarBuillder = new GrammarBuilder(greeting);
        GrammarBuilder DateAndTimeGrammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(DateAndTime);

        //put the grammar builder inside the grammar
        greetingGrammar = new Grammar(greetingGrammarBuillder);
        greetingGrammar.Name = "GreetingGrammar";
        DateAndTimeGrammar = new Grammar(DateAndTimeGrammarBuilder);
        DateAndTimeGrammar.Name = "DateAndTimeGrammar";

        rec.LoadGrammar(greetingGrammar);
        rec.LoadGrammar(DateAndTimeGrammar);

    }
}
```

and here is the main page :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    DefineGrammar gr = new DefineGrammar();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        gr.LoadGrammar();
        rec.SpeechRecognized += Rec_SpeechRecognized;
        rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling LoadGrammarAsync which I imagine is asyncronous and has not completed by the time you call RecognizeAsync?

Comment: *i get this error* is that an exception? if so, please include it in your question, so we can examine the stack and pinpoint the call that's causing the issue.

Comment: i try to use LoadGrammar and i have same problem

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: ok i will edit the question

Comment: i edit the question @AndreasNiedermair

Comment: i edit the question @Fildor

Comment: You are loading the Grammar to a different instance of the SpeechRecognitionEngine. It's like you put fuel in a different car - yours will still run dry ;)

Comment: But what is the solution if i remove the SpeechRecognitionEngine instance how can i load the grammar @Fildor

Comment: Answer in progress ...

Comment: @AliMardini you are missing the stack trace, please do `exception.ToString()` and add the result to your question.

Comment: Although already solved, you should consider @AndreasNiedermair 's advice for your next question. It is so much easier to get to problem when we have a stacktrace.

Comment: ok thank for advice i will do that for sure :) thank you all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DefineGrammar class, you have a member field of type SpeechRecognitionEngine to which you load the grammar if `LoadGrammar()` is invoked.

In your main class, you have *a different* instance of that type on which you try to invoke recognition.

Now, the error is that you have two separate instances of SpeechRecognitionEngine.

One way to solve this could be to change your DefineGrammar as follows:

Instead of `public void LoadGrammar()` make it `public void LoadGrammar( SpeechRecognitionEngine rec )` and remove the member field `rec` in that class.

There are other possibilities but this will do the job. The difference is that now you load the Grammar to the instance that is used in your main class, not a different one.