# Issue with recognising speech in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, speech-recognition

I was coding a speech recognition application, and I found an example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB9lfHDOe5U). I was following the code as close as possible, only with little variation, but then when I launched the application I caught the InnerException, on line 24, specifically the

> At least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition

issue. I have copied the code line to line (in educational purposes), so I am pretty sure that it must work, but for some reason it does not. My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Voice_Recognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnDisable.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnDisable.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "say hello", "say goodbye", "say my name" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(RecEngine_SpeechRecognized);
        }

        private void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "say hello":
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello to you!");
                    break;
                case "say goodbye":
                    MessageBox.Show("Bye, bye!");
                    break;
                case "say my name":
                    InputBox.Text += "\nYourName";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I do not think, that is the issue, though.

P.S. I am aware, that similar question has already been asked [here on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065410/c-sharp-voice-recognition-issue); however, my question is a little different, since all of the above code looks correct to me.

Comment: Where is line 24? Please add comment in code were exception occurs

Comment: recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Form1_Load` will never be executed if you dont register the [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You can do that in your constructor.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += Form1_Load;
}
```

I suppose in the example this line was in the designer file.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this solution.

Comment: @L_Pav allways a pleasure